# How to update Pandas DF using a MAP file, but leave the default value if there is no key pair

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have a dataframe and some of the values need to be updated.  However, I want to leave the values without a key value as it currently is.

I tried other code but when I run the code it changes all the values without a key pair to NaN.

How do I go from

```
Df

City       Employer
Toronto    Magna's Automotive
Toronto    Manga
Vancouver  Dunder
Calgary    Flames
```

mapping file

```
d = {'Manga':"Magna's Automotive",
     'Dunder': 'Dunder Mifflin',}
```

Df-desired

```
City       Employer
Toronto    Magna's Automotive
Toronto    Magna's Automotive
Vancouver  Dunder Mifflin
Calgary    Flames
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
df['Employer'] = df['Employer'].map(d).fillna(df['Employer'])
```

output:

```
        City            Employer
0    Toronto  Magna's Automotive
1    Toronto  Magna's Automotive
2  Vancouver      Dunder Mifflin
3    Calgary              Flames
```

Or, using `update` for in place modification:

```py
df.update(df['Employer'].map(d))
```